# Pandas pivot_table drops rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datasource that provides me with data of the following structure:

```
| timestamp                | tagid       | value        |
|--------------------------|-------------|--------------|
| 01.01.2018 00:00:00:01   | 1           | 100.0        |
| 01.01.2018 00:00:00:01   | 1           | 101.0        |
| 01.01.2018 00:00:00:01   | 2           | 99.0         |
| 01.01.2018 00:00:00:02   | 2           | 120.0        |
| 01.01.2018 00:00:00:02   | 3           | 150.0        |
| 01.01.2018 00:00:00:02   | 3           | 12.0         |
```

I want it to look like the following

```
| 1       | 2       | 3       | As you can see, I get two rows, because I 
|---------|---------|---------| have two instances of every TAGID
|  100.0  |  99.0   |  150.0  |
|  101.0  |  120.0  |  12.0   |
```

This means I have to use a pivot table. My code for this is:

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['timestamp'], columns=['tagid'], values='value')
```

This works, to an extent. The new datastructure is exactly how I want it to be. The problem is that I'm missing rows that should be there. I've already tried the flags "fill_value" and "dropna", but to no effect.

**This is my thought process:**

My (real) dataset has 9360 rows and I have 144 seperate tags. That means the 144 seperate tags have to repeat 9360 / 144 = 65 times. I have verified this manually.

Anyways, for some reason I cannot see I get less than 65 rows, namely 35.
As far as I can tell, the data is clean enough for this to work.

I feel like I'm missing a crucial detail here, please help me find that detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way from `crosstab` , create the `index` by using `cumcount` is the key for your question (PS: , `pivot` , `pivot_table` , `stack` `unstack` also work ,after you create the key )

```
pd.crosstab(df.groupby('tagid').cumcount(),df.tagid,df.value,aggfunc='mean')
Out[947]: 
tagid      1      2      3
row_0                     
0      100.0   99.0  150.0
1      101.0  120.0   12.0
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Just for me to understand: Why was the index I set wrong? Maybe because it could have been the same for multiple rows and then pandas only grabbed the unique ones? Or am I completely off track here?

Comment: @DanielKrenn index and column combined should be unique , in your case , since it is not unique , the value will be aggregated by the aggfunc